# make a list of tuples with a number of elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list :

```
['replace', 't', 'T', 'replace', 'r', 'R', 'replace', 'a', 'e', 'replace', 'a', 'e', 'replace', 'M', 'm', 'delete', ' ', 'a', 'replace', 'p', 'o', 'insert', 'r', 'o', 'insert', 'r', 'o', 'insert', 'r', 'o', 'insert', 'r', 'o', 'insert', 'r', 'o', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 't', 'a', 'insert', 't', 'a', 'insert', 't', 'a', 'insert', 't', 'a', 'insert', 't', 'a', 'insert', 't', 'a', 'insert', 't', 'a', 'insert', 't', 'a', 'replace', 't', 'a', 'replace', 'e', 'e', 'replace', ' ', 'r', 'insert', ' ', 'd', 'replace', ' ', 'd', 'replace', 'i', 'e', 'replace', 'l', 's']
```

how can i create a list containing tuples of three items from my first list ?

**Output** :

```
[('replace', 't', 'T'), ('replace', 'r', 'R'), ('replace', 'a', 'e'), ('replace', 'a', 'e'), ...]
```

Also, can I use comprehension list, to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip()`:

```
lst = ['replace', 't', 'T', 'replace', 'r', 'R', 'replace', 'a', 'e', 'replace', 'a', 'e', 'replace', 'M', 'm', 'delete', ' ', 'a', 'replace', 'p', 'o', 'insert', 'r', 'o', 'insert', 'r', 'o', 'insert', 'r', 'o', 'insert', 'r', 'o', 'insert', 'r', 'o', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 'e', 'm', 'insert', 't', 'a', 'insert', 't', 'a', 'insert', 't', 'a', 'insert', 't', 'a', 'insert', 't', 'a', 'insert', 't', 'a', 'insert', 't', 'a', 'insert', 't', 'a', 'replace', 't', 'a', 'replace', 'e', 'e', 'replace', ' ', 'r', 'insert', ' ', 'd', 'replace', ' ', 'd', 'replace', 'i', 'e', 'replace', 'l', 's']

print(list(zip(lst[::3], lst[1::3], lst[2::3])))
```

Prints:

```
[('replace', 't', 'T'), ('replace', 'r', 'R'), ('replace', 'a', 'e'), ('replace', 'a', 'e'), ('replace', 'M', 'm'), ('delete', ' ', 'a'), ('replace', 'p', 'o'), ('insert', 'r', 'o'), ('insert', 'r', 'o'), ('insert', 'r', 'o'), ('insert', 'r', 'o'), ('insert', 'r', 'o'), ('insert', 'e', 'm'), ('insert', 'e', 'm'), ('insert', 'e', 'm'), ('insert', 'e', 'm'), ('insert', 'e', 'm'), ('insert', 'e', 'm'), ('insert', 'e', 'm'), ('insert', 'e', 'm'), ('insert', 'e', 'm'), ('insert', 'e', 'm'), ('insert', 'e', 'm'), ('insert', 't', 'a'), ('insert', 't', 'a'), ('insert', 't', 'a'), ('insert', 't', 'a'), ('insert', 't', 'a'), ('insert', 't', 'a'), ('insert', 't', 'a'), ('insert', 't', 'a'), ('replace', 't', 'a'), ('replace', 'e', 'e'), ('replace', ' ', 'r'), ('insert', ' ', 'd'), ('replace', ' ', 'd'), ('replace', 'i', 'e'), ('replace', 'l', 's')]
```